# How to use layout inflater and addview inside a list item which are clickable

Tags: android, json, listview

I have a JSON array which looks like the following. I need to populate a listview using this array but I have another array inside the JSON (for the comments) which I hope to use to populate a linearlayout inside a list item using `addview()`. How can I design my list adapter, I need the comments to be clickable too.

```
[
{
    "name": "Hopewell Mutanda",
    "answer": "This is my answer",
    "votes": 10,
    "date": 20-06-2014,
    "comments": [
                 {
                    "comment": "This is a great answer",
                    "name": "Gloria Nyakudya",
                    "date": 21-10-2014,
                    "vote": 20,
                 },
                 {
                    "comment": "This is the second great answer",
                    "name": "Pelagia Chirenga",
                    "date": 21-10-2014,
                    "vote": 10,
                 },
                 {
                    "comment": "This is the third great answer",
                    "name": "Pelagia Chirenga",
                    "date": 21-10-2014,
                    "vote": 0,
                 },
                ]
},
 {
    "name": "Tinashe Makaza",
    "answer": "This is the second  answer",
    "votes": 10,
    "date": 20-06-2014,
    "comments": [
                 {
                    "comment": "This is a great answer",
                    "name": "Gloria Nyakudya",
                    "date": 21-10-2014,
                    "vote": 20,
                 },
                 {
                    "comment": "This is the second great answer",
                    "name": "Pelagia Chirenga",
                    "date": 21-10-2014,
                    "vote": 10,
                 },
                 {
                    "comment": "This is the third great answer",
                    "name": "Pelagia Chirenga",
                    "date": 21-10-2014,
                    "vote": 0,
                 },
                ]
},

]
```

This is the link to the image of something I hope to achieve. Every value in this layout is hard coded

http://encodable.com/uploaddemo/files/Screenshot_2014-12-02-23-55-33.png

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html). This is the default two level `ListView`. Seems to me that fits your needs exactly.